# Find out whether there is a route between two nodes in a drected graph

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I tried to solve this problem using DFS. My code is as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // building a graph g. g has a method getNodes() that can return all the nodes in the graph.
    // ...
    for(GraphNode n : g.getNodes())
        n.state = State.Unvistied;
    node1.state = State.Visiting;
    isRoute(g, node1, node2);
}

public boolean isRoute(Graph g, GraphNode start, GraphNode end){
    for(GraphNode gn : start.getAdjacent()){
        if(gn.state != State.Visited){
            if(gn == end)
                return true;
            else {
                gn.state = State.Visiting;
                if(isRoute(g, gn, end))
                    return true;    
            }
        }               
    }
    start.state = State.Visited;
    return false;
}

class GraphNode {
    private GraphNode adjacent[];
    private String vertex;
    public State state;

    public GraphNode(String vertex, int adjacentLength) {
        this.vertex = vertex;
        adjacent = new GraphNode[adjacentLength];
    }

    public GraphNode[] getAdjacent() {
        return adjacent;
    }

    public String getVertex() {
        return vertex;
    }
}

public enum State {

    Unvistied, Visited, Visiting;

}
```

I have tried to run this algorithm on paper with an example graph and it seems right. **However, I don't know how to make sure, i.e prove that this algorithm, especially when it is recursive and not easy to run test cases as it is in a graph, is correct.** Can you guys give me some insights on that? Thank you!

Comment: If your GraphNode had a method addAdjacent(Graphnode) you could hard-code tests for various test-cases.